# Little Snitch: how to selectively allow a single script to access the internet?

Tags: macos, firewall, little-snitch

I have a python script that accesses the web and each time it launches I'm prompted by my Little Snitch to allow the connection by Python.

I don't want to allow globally allow Python to connect, since theoretically some rogue app could use the system's python for phoning home etc.

Is there some way to have just this specific script (by, say, system path) to automatically be allowed web access? Or perhaps is there a way to programmatically dismiss the Little Snitch dialog box and allow the connection from inside the script?

Comment: I think you might be able to install (or copy) a second version of python to another directory (maybe to `/usr/local/bin/`) and rename it, then tell your script to use `/usr/local/bin/your_python` instead of the usual `/usr/bin/python`. Maybe Little Snitch will be able to create a rule for this one only.

Comment: Maybe what @slhck suggested works with creating a symbolic link to the python binary and referencing that one in the shebang-line of your script?

Comment: great ideas you guys